# How to use pandas UDF in pyspark and return result in StructType

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

How can I drive a column based on panda-udf in pyspark. I've written udf as below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf("in_type string, in_var string, in_numer int", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)

def getSplitOP(in_data):
    if in_data is None or len(in_data) < 1:
        return None
    #Input/variable.12-2017
    splt=in_data.split("/",1)
    in_type=splt[0]

    splt_1=splt[1].split(".",1)
    in_var = splt_1[0]

    splt_2=splt_1[1].split("-",1)
    in_numer=int(splt_2[0])

    return (in_type, in_var, in_numer)
    #Expected output: ("input", "variable", 12)

df = df.withColumn("splt_col", getSplitOP(df.In_data))
```

Can someone help me out to identify, what's wrong with above code, and why it's not working.

Comment: It might be useful to see the outcome of executing this code.

Comment: Why use a pandas udf here? You can do this with a regular udf or even with the standard API functions.

Comment: I was looking for pandas udf, as they are fast as compared to normal udf. So I was looking for their implementation.

Comment: I believe pandas udf are more faster than regular udf.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("input/variable.12-2017",), ("output/invariable.11-2018",)], ("in_data",))
df.show()

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf("in_type string, in_var string, in_numer int", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def getSplitOP(pdf):
    in_data = pdf.in_data

    #Input/variable.12-2017
    splt = in_data.apply(lambda x: x.split("/",1))
    in_type = splt.apply(lambda x: x[0])

    splt_1 = splt.apply(lambda x: x[1].split(".",1))
    in_var = splt_1.apply(lambda x: x[0])

    splt_2 = splt_1.apply(lambda x: x[1].split("-",1))
    in_numer = splt_2.apply(lambda x: int(x[0]))

    return pd.DataFrame({"in_type": in_type, "in_var": in_var, "in_numer": in_numer})
    #Expected output: ("input", "variable", 12)

df = df.groupBy().apply(getSplitOP)
df.show()
```

- There must not be a blank line after @pandas_udf.
- pandas Series objects don't directly support string functions such as split.  Use `apply` to operate elementwise on each Series.
- You used a GROUPED_MAP in order to return multiple columns, but your code isn't inherently grouped by anything.  Note that groupBy is used without any arguments here.  This requires all the data to fit on a single processor.

Comment: Is there any documentation link to pandas_udf struct type or array type usage?

Comment: @hwrd do you think fitting all the data in a single processor wouldn't be a performance issue, the reason of using Pandas UDF is improving the performance anyway

Comment: @boozy In order to avoid clobbering the driver, OP would have to supply something to group on.  Spark partitions the data into manageable chunks for the non-grouped UDFs.  The OP should use or create suitable column(s) to use in `groupBy` to ensure that each worker receives a manageable chunk.